NO ME APARECEN LAS IMAGENES EN PHAZSER
Holaaa, estoy aprendiendo a usar phaser y no entiendo por que las imágenes no me aparecen, estoy usando live server, están bien las rutas y todo pero aun así sigue sin aparecer, aquí mi código en JS
    const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update,
    }
};

    const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    
    function preload() {
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    }
    
    function create() {
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    }
    
    function update() {
    
    }


Prueba pasando una intancia de Phaser.Scene como scene en el config, puedes hacerlo así:
Crea una clase que extienda de la clase Phaser.Scene y define los métodos preload, create y update dentro de esta nueva clase:
class Escena extends Phaser.Scene
{
    
    preload (){
            this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
            this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
            this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
            this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
            this.load.spritesheet('dude',
                'assets/dude.png',
                { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 }
            );
            
    }

    create (){
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    }


    update(){ 

    }

    ///más métodos si quieres o necesitas
}

Despues pasas esa escena en el config así:
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1024,
    height: 600,
    scene: Escena
};

Y ya ahora si  inicializas en Phaser.Game con
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

Cabe mencionar que en mi caso las imágenes están en una carpeta /assets que se encuentra al mismo nivel del index.html donde estoy iniciando phaser. La versión que me funciona con el código actual es phaser 3.60.0. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.60.0/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js
